# Remove suffix of the column names and unpivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot, suffix

I'd like to unpivot the following table with column names "Year", "Item", and "$". My workaround is to separate the table into two dataframes and remove the suffixes, then concatenate the two columns vertically. Are there any other easier ways to approach this?

Example Dataframe:

```
data = {'Year_x': [1993, 1994, 1995, 1996], 
       'Year_y': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003],
       'Item_x':['A','B','C','D'],
       'Item_y':['E','F','G','H'],
       '$':[3,4,5,6]}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

| Year_x | Year_y | Item_x | Item_y | $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1993 | 2000 | A | E | 3 |
| 1994 | 2001 | B | F | 4 |
| 1995 | 2002 | C | G | 5 |
| 1996 | 2003 | D | H | 6 |

What I want to achieve:

| Year | Item | $ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1993 | A | 3 |
| 1994 | B | 4 |
| 1995 | C | 5 |
| 1995 | D | 6 |
| 2000 | E | 3 |
| 2001 | F | 4 |
| 2002 | G | 5 |
| 2003 | H | 6 |

Comment: with `pyjanitor`, you can achieve this as well : ``import janitor; df.pivot_longer(index = "$", names_to=".value", names_pattern=r"(.+)_.*")``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenation with list comprehension

```
>>> pd.concat([df[["Year_" + c, "Item_" + c, "$"]].rename({"Year_" + c : "Year", "Item_" + c : "Item"}, axis=1) for c in ("x", "y")]).reset_index(drop=True)
   Year Item  $
0  1993    A  3
1  1994    B  4
2  1995    C  5
3  1996    D  6
4  2000    E  3
5  2001    F  4
6  2002    G  5
7  2003    H  6
```

Or, via `pd.wide_to_long(...)`

```
>>> pd.wide_to_long(df, ["Year", "Item"], i=["$"], j="Var", sep="_", suffix="\w+").reset_index()
   $ Var  Year Item
0  3   x  1993    A
1  4   x  1994    B
2  5   x  1995    C
3  6   x  1996    D
4  3   y  2000    E
5  4   y  2001    F
6  5   y  2002    G
7  6   y  2003    H
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would work perfectly if there are only a few column names to edit like the example I give above, but often times there are more.

Comment: Added another example with standard pandas tool `wide_to_long`

Comment: I like your second approach. I know it's Regex, but could you explain more on the" \w+"? What does it do?

Comment: @Jamie `\w+` matches one or more chars after the `sep='_'` symbol. By default, pd.wide_to_long looks for digits. Check its help page, it is very good written https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for convert columns without separator `_` to index, then split columns names to `MultiIndex` :

```
cols = ['$']
#if multiple columns
cols = ['$', '$Column1', '$Column2']
df1 = df.set_index(cols)

df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = (df1.stack()
          .sort_values(['Item','Year'])
          .reset_index()[['Year','Item'] + cols])
print (df1)
   Year Item  $
0  1993    A  3
1  1994    B  4
2  1995    C  5
3  1996    D  6
4  2000    E  3
5  2001    F  4
6  2002    G  5
7  2003    H  6
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if I have multiple value columns, for example $Column1, $ Column2, $Column3? I can't set them all to index right?

Comment: @Jamie - Sure, exaclty.

Comment: If there are '$Column1' and  '$Column2', I think the reset_index level part would eliminate them

Comment: @Jamie - you are right, removed first `reset_index`

Answer (score 0):

- step1, find suffix of the columns

```py
df_col = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.str.split('_').tolist())
df_col['col'] = df.columns.tolist()
print(df_col)

    #       0     1     col
    # 0  Year     x  Year_x
    # 1  Year     y  Year_y
    # 2  Item     x  Item_x
    # 3  Item     y  Item_y
    # 4     $  None       $
```

- step2, handle the output columns

```py
cond =  df_col[1].isnull()
cols_without_subfix = df_col.loc[cond, 'col'].tolist()
obj = df_col[~cond].groupby(1)['col'].agg(list)
obj = obj.map(lambda x: x + cols_without_subfix)
print(obj)

    # 1
    # x    [Year_x, Item_x, $]
    # y    [Year_y, Item_y, $]
    # Name: col, dtype: object
```

- step3, iter the output columns and concat them.

```
df_list = []
for i in obj:
    dfn = df[i]
    dfn.columns = dfn.columns.str.split('_').str[0]
    df_list.append(dfn)
df_output = pd.concat(df_list)    
print(df_output)

    #    Year Item  $
    # 0  1993    A  3
    # 1  1994    B  4
    # 2  1995    C  5
    # 3  1996    D  6
    # 0  2000    E  3
    # 1  2001    F  4
    # 2  2002    G  5
    # 3  2003    H  6
```